# (C#) Is there a way to set the value of a single bit through pointers?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

What I mean is: Imagine we have a 8 byte variable that has a high value and low value. I can make one pointer point to the upper 4 bytes and other point to the lower 4 bytes, and set/retrieve their values without problems. Now, is there a way to get/set values for anything smaller than a byte? If instead of dividing it in two 4 bytes "variables", I'd want to consider eight 1 byte variables I could use a bool, but there is no defined smaller variable in c#. Would it possible to divide it to 16 just with pointers? Or even in 32, 64? It wouldn't right?

This is a pretty academic question, I know this can be achieved otherwise with bitshiffting, unions(Struct.Explicit), etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, C# does not support bit fields and a byte is the minimum amount of addressable memory. You can manually provide properties that change one or several specific bits but you have to provide packing/unpacking logic yourself:

```
public bool Bit5 {
    get { return (field & 32) != 0; }
    set { if (value) field |= 32; else field &= ~32; }
}
```

By the way, I don't know how you achieve it using `LayoutKind.Explicit` as the minimum `FieldOffset` you can specify is one **byte**.

As a side note, even C++ that can do this with bit fields will just *hide* the bitwise tricks and makes the compiler do it instead of you. There's no way you could grab something less than a byte from memory to a register, at least on x86 architecture.

Comment: Hm, could you explain your code? I don't understand a lot about bit manipulation. I can understand the "field & 32" but not the != 0.

Comment: `32` is `2^5 = 100000`. If the result of bitwise and of field and 32 is zero, bit 5 has to be zero. Otherwise, it has to be 1.

Comment: Ah, yes. That was obvious. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, even on x86, you're always fetching at least 32 bits of memory to a register. The "load byte" CISC instructions simply translate to a load-word followed by a mask in the actual trace.

Comment: @Mehdrad: it better style to express bitmasks in hexadecimal; e.g. 0x20 instead of 32.  Lots of folks cannot do hex <-> decimal conversions in their heads.

Comment: @Stephen: I wanted to write it as `(1 << 5)`. I thought it would just complicate things. Anyway, after all, if you are trying to do something like this, you should be comfortable with bitwise operations.